# Why does Json.NET not include $type for the root object when TypeNameHandling is Auto?

Tags: serialization, types, json.net

When I set Json.NET to serialize with TypeNameHandling set to TypeNameHandling.Auto, it correctly sets $type for child properties of an object but does not do so for the root object being serialized. Why?

Please consider the following repro:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal[] Offspring { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal {}

Animal fido = new Dog
{
    Offspring = new Animal[] { new Dog() }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fido, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    });
```

The Json emitted into the `json` variable is:

```
{
    "Offspring": [{
        "$type": "MyApp.Dog, MyApp",
        "Offspring": null
    }]
}
```

The Json.NET [Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) says that for `TypeNameHandling.Auto` the behavior is:

> Include the .NET type name when the type of the object being serialized is not the same as its declared type.

My question is - Why does fido not have 
`"$type": "MyApp.Dog, MyApp",` like its puppy? :)

---

**UPDATE:** I've found out from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356336/json-net-how-to-add-property-type-only-on-root-object) that I can force $type to be added by doing this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fido,
    typeof(Animal),
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    });
```

But my question still holds - Why does Json.NET not do this by itself as per the documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json.net - how to add property $type ONLY on root object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356336/json-net-how-to-add-property-type-only-on-root-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: it doesn't because it *can't*.

As you stated in your question, setting `TypeNameHandling` to `Auto` directs Json.Net to include the .NET type name when the actual (run-time) type of the object being serialized is not the same as its declared (compile-time) type.  In order to do that, Json.Net needs to know both types for every object.

For everything inside the root object, this is straightforward: just get the runtime type of the root object via `GetType()`, then use reflection to get all of its declared properties and their types, and for each one compare the declared type to the actual type to see if they differ.  If they do, output the type name.

But for the root object itself, Json.Net doesn't have access to both types.  All the information it has is the object referenced by `fido`, whose runtime type is `Dog`.  There's no way for Json.Net to discover that the `fido` variable was declared as `Animal`, unless you provide that context somehow.  And that is exactly why Json.Net provides overloads of [`SerializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_7.htm) which allow you to specify the compile-time type of the object being serialized.  You *must* use one of these overloads if you want the `TypeNameHandling.Auto` setting to work for the root object.

Comment: You can in newer versions: `ser.Serialize(stream, object, typeof(BaseClass));` Where you pass the base class to the serialize method, and TypeNameHandling will write the $type if the object and expected type do not match.

Comment: @PopCatalin Right. That is what I said in the last two sentences of my answer above.

Comment: And how do you get it to use one of those SerializeObject overloads in ASP.NET Core's serialization mechanism in controllers?

Comment: @rory.ap Sounds like a good candidate for a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 2):

Brian is absolutely correct, Json.NET has no way of knowing the compile-time declared type of the object it's being passed as the `value` parameter is declared as an `object`. The easy fix for this was if Json.NET added generic serialize methods so that the compile-time declared type would automatically flow over to Json.NET but the library's author has decided against my proposal for this [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/634).

As an alternative, I've wrapped all my json (de)serialization needs in a `JsonHelper` class with generic serialize methods which use the `typeof` expression to automatically pass the compile-time declared type of the value to be serialized.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I thought that the type to be specified should be the type of the object, but actually it should **differ** from the objects actual type to write out the type. Simply put, if you want it to always give the root type, add `typeof(object)` to the methods and not `typeof(myObject)`

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Json.Net allow you to pass the expected type to the serialize method

```
 ser.Serialize(stream, rootObject, typeof(BaseClass));
```

You can pass the base class to the serialize method and `TypeNameHandling.Auto` will write the $type if the object and expected type do not match.

Comment: So easy. Thank you for this!