# Type information appears when serializing list of objects but not single object using Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have encountered an interesting scenario that i don't understand about Json.Net.

I need to serialize objects in order to POST them to API. Objects are created using types with some hierarchy. So in the serialization methods, **base type** is used to receive the object/objects and serialize it/them using Json.Net with TypeNameHandling.Auto configured.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SerializationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dj = new Dj() { Name = "Tim", Label = "UMG", StageName = "Avicii" };
            var djJson = JSerializer.Serialize(dj);

            var djs = new List<Person>();
            djs.Add(dj);
            var djsJson = JSerializer.Serialize(djs);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class JSerializer
    {
        public static string Serialize(Person person)
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });

            return result;
        }

        public static string Serialize(IReadOnlyList<Person> people)
        {
            var eventModelsSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people, Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
                });

            return eventModelsSerialized;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Artist : Person
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dj : Artist
    {
        public string StageName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What happens then is that:
for single object serialization case, I got very basic Json without any type information:

```
   {
      "StageName": "Avicii",
      "Label": "UMG",
      "Name": "Tim"
    }
```

while for list of objects serialization case, we got Json with type information:

```
[
  {
    "$type": "SerializationTest.Dj, SerializationTest",
    "StageName": "Avicii",
    "Label": "UMG",
    "Name": "Tim"
  }
]
```

This creats confusion for server side. So when I want to just serialize single object, the server side has problem to serialize it due to lack of type information. So the workaround is creating a list to include the object and serialize as list instead.

Could anyone explain why Json.Net serialize differently for these two cases? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Serializing an interface/abstract object using NewtonSoft.JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28128923/3744182).  Also related: [Why does Json.NET not include $type for the root object when TypeNameHandling is Auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38859074) and [json.net - how to add property $type ONLY on root object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36356336/3744182).

Comment: @dbc thanks for your comments. These links explain how to enable $type for the root object which really helps me improve code for serializing single object. But they don't mention why the $type is added automatically when tying to serialize a list. Do you have any more thoughts about that?

Comment: Because, when serializing a list, the `var dj = new Dj() ` is no longer the root object -- the `List<Person>()` is the root object.  So `TypeNameHandling.Auto` now applies.

Comment: @dbc that's correct. Thanks. I think i understand it now.

Answer (score -2):

you can wrap your object as given below

```
   var dj = new Dj() { Name = "Tim", Label = "UMG", StageName = "Avicii" };
    var obj = new 
    {
        Dj = dj
    };

            var eventModelsSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented,
               new JsonSerializerSettings
               {
                   TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
               });
```

Result with type information:

```
{
  "Dj": {
    "StageName": "Avicii",
    "Label": "UMG",
    "Name": "Tim"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a type information, but rather property information of higher level object that you created. the name can be anything, also adding custom field or etc may do the trick, but standard json parsers won't follow such trick, and cannot deserialize it