# Why typename handling does not affect guid in NewtonsoftJson and how to deal with it?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I expect the applied code to return something like `{"$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Guid", "value": "34861761826d4419a2084ef161992616"}`  (It's `TypeNameHandling.All` job and
it works with more complex types)

But instead I get just `"34861761826d4419a2084ef161992616"`

So, when I try to `var guid = (Guid)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialised, jsonSettings);` it fails, cause deserialization returns a string. (I do not use generic
deserializer due to some complex reasons based on generating a huge amount of code around existing base)

Minimal code:

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

            var serialised = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(guid, jsonSettings);
            Console.WriteLine(serialised);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `TypeNameHandling` only applies to objects and arrays, not primitives.  See [NewtonSoft SerializeObject ignores TypeNameHandling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61900664/3744182), which looks to be a duplicate.  Agree?

Comment: @dbc Could you convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I can make it a duplicate.

Comment: Convert it to a duplicate please