Type resolution in Newtonsoft.Json with custom converter
I have an issue trying to deserialize ScriptableObjects in Unity. I am using the  Newtonsoft.Json library as I want to resolve types, however this seems to conflict with using a custom converter. Without using a CustomCreationConverter the code properly resolves types, however Unity complains about ScriptableObjects being created using new(). When I add the Converter, everything is being cast to the base class, instead of the appropriate subclass.
How can I ensure types are being resolved even while using a Converter?
Code sample of my Loader:
 public abstract class Database<T> : ScriptableObject where T : ScriptableObject {
    public T LoadEntry(string path)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings =
            new()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            };
        settings.Converters.Add(new ScriptableObjectConverter());

        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);

        T entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContent, settings);

        return entry;
    }

    private class ScriptableObjectConverter : CustomCreationConverter<T>
    {
        public override T Create(Type objectType)
        {
            Debug.Log(objectType);
            return CreateInstance<T>();
        }
    }
}


Why not use the built-in JsonUtility in this case? I know it is more limited than Newtonsoft .. but it is literally made for handling Unity API specifics and you would simply do a JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite ...

JsonUtility does not have any type resolution to my knowledge, and neither does it allow for any customization I need for serializing references.

When you write your own JsonConverter for a given type, you must handle everything yourself, including reading and writing of metadata properties such as "$type" and "$id".  It's a bit of a nuisance but certainly possible, see Using custom JsonConverter and TypeNameHandling in Json.net and How to deserialize json objects into specific subclasses? for examples.
That being said, since the only custom logic you need is to substitute in a call to ScriptableObject.CreateInstance() for your default constructor, there's an easier way: you could create a custom contract resolver that overrides DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract() and sets JsonContract.DefaultCreator.  To do this, create the following contract resolver:
class ScriptableObjectContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (typeof(ScriptableObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && !objectType.IsAbstract)
        {
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(objectType);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}

Then use it e.g. as follows:
//Newtonsoft recommends caching resolvers statically for best performance, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver
static readonly ScriptableObjectContractResolver resolver = new();

public T LoadEntry(string path)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings =
        new()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            ContractResolver = resolver,
        };

    using (var textReader = new StreamReader(path, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
    {
        return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<T>(jsonReader); // Add some check for a returned null value here?
    }
}

public void SaveEntry(string path, T entry)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings =
        new()
        {
            // Note that TypeNameHandling.Auto is never respected for the ROOT JSON object, for confirmation see
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859074/why-does-json-net-not-include-type-for-the-root-object-when-typenamehandling-is
            // So you need to use a different TypeNameHandling value or follow the workaround from 
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356336/json-net-how-to-add-property-type-only-on-root-object
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            ContractResolver = resolver,
        };
    using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
    {
        JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(jsonWriter, entry);
    }
}

Notes:

Json.NET will not serialize a "$type" property for the root object when using TypeNameHandling.Auto.  For why, see Why does Json.NET not include $type for the root object when TypeNameHandling is Auto?.  If you need type information for your root object you must use a different setting, or the workaround from json.net - how to add property $type ONLY on root object.

It is more efficient to serialize directly from and to a FileStream than to serialize from and to a string, then write and read the string.

Please be aware that there are security risks associated with TypeNameHandling. As explained in the docs:

TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For details see TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json and External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?.


Mockup fiddle here.

If you want to deserialize a json file into its subclass, you need to manually judge its type and use is or something to convert it into the corresponding subclass. because deserialization itself cannot determine what type your data was originally, the data that cannot be deserialized will be discarded and processed manually.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
