# TypeNameHandling with attribute on a class

Tags: c#, json.net

I use [TypeNameHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) to serialize and deserialize a list of derived class in json.
It work perfectly with a property and the attribute `JsonProperty`

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public bool CanFly { get; set;}
}

public class FlyingAnimal : Animal
{
    public FlyingAnimal() { this.CanFly = true; }
}

public class SwimmingAnimal : Animal
{
    public SwimmingAnimal() { this.CanFly = false; }
}

public class World
{
    public World() { 
        this.Animals = new List<Animal>(); 
        this.Animals.Add(new FlyingAnimal());
        this.Animals.Add(new SwimmingAnimal());
    }

    [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need a WebAPI returning a list of derived class:

```
[RoutePrefix("Animals")]
public class AnimalsController : ApiController
{
    public List<Animal> Get()
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>(); 
        animals.Add(new FlyingAnimal());
        animals.Add(new SwimmingAnimal());
        return animals;
    }
}
```

Is there an attribute to put on the base class to include the type in the serialization? I tried without success :

```
[JsonObject(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
public abstract class Animal
```

I know i can change the `JsonSerializerSettings` but i want a solution with an attribute on the base class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no functionality to do this out-of-the box in Json.NET, but you could do it with a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class| AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class AddJsonTypenameAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}

public class AddJsonTypenameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    // See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information
    static AddJsonTypenameContractResolver instance;

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static AddJsonTypenameContractResolver() { instance = new AddJsonTypenameContractResolver(); }

    public static AddJsonTypenameContractResolver Instance { get { return instance; } }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization)
            .ApplyAddTypenameAttribute();
    }

    protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
    {
        return base.CreateArrayContract(objectType)
            .ApplyAddTypenameAttribute();
    }
}

public static class ContractResolverExtensions
{
    public static JsonProperty ApplyAddTypenameAttribute(this JsonProperty jsonProperty)
    {
        if (jsonProperty.TypeNameHandling == null)
        {
            if (jsonProperty.PropertyType.GetCustomAttribute<AddJsonTypenameAttribute>(false) != null)
            {
                jsonProperty.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
            }
        }
        return jsonProperty;
    }

    public static JsonArrayContract ApplyAddTypenameAttribute(this JsonArrayContract contract)
    {
        if (contract.ItemTypeNameHandling == null)
        {
            if (contract.CollectionItemType.GetCustomAttribute<AddJsonTypenameAttribute>(false) != null)
            {
                contract.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
            }
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your interfaces or base types as follows:

```
[AddJsonTypename]
public interface IAnimal
{
    bool CanFly { get; }
}

[AddJsonTypename]
public abstract class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public bool CanFly { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the attribute is marked with [`Inherited = false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx).  This means a `List<Animal>` will have type information inserted automatically but a `List<FlyingAnimal>` will not.  Also note that this will not force type information to be emitted for a root object. If you need this, see perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361605/3744182).

Finally, to use the contract resolver with Web API, see for instance [Web API 2: how to return JSON with camelCased property names, on objects and their sub-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28552567/3744182).  And do take note of this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182), [How to configure Json.NET to create a vulnerable web API](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html), and Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's blackhat paper https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in the newer Json.NET versions (10+).

Comment: @Hele - I just reran my unit tests in Json.NET 11.0.2 and they passed successfully.  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem?

Comment: @Hele - the problem is that you are applying `[AddJsonTypename]` to the root object, but unfortunately the answer is documented not to work for the root object: *Also note that this will not force type information to be emitted for a root object. If you need this, see perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361605/3744182).*

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that warning. It so happens I found that link and used that solution anyway. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not ideal, but you could try this as a simple workaround:

```
[JsonArray(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
public class AnimalList : List<Animal>
{ }
```

Then:

```
[RoutePrefix("Animals")]
public class AnimalsController : ApiController
{
    public List<Animal> Get()
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new AnimalList(); 
        animals.Add(new FlyingAnimal());
        animals.Add(new SwimmingAnimal());
        return animals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but with this workaround in a team each developer must know that he must create a ListAnimals instead of List<Animals> to seriialize the list. So i hoped a solution more flexible

Comment: No need to teach each developer to use this class. Simply hide it in the implementation of a class and expose List<Animal> in the interface. All consumers just know List<Animal> but internally you wrap the List<Animal> into a AnimalList. Works perfectly and is easier than copying JsonSerializerSettings across my software.