# Control emmission of type information for specific types or properties

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm serialising several types to JSON. *Some* of these types have type discriminator properties, with custom `JsonConverter`s used to aid deserialisation.

The JSON serialiser is configured with `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects`, because for many types I want the full type name to be serialised in the `$type` element.

What I'd like to do is be able to leave `TypeNameHandling` enabled by default, but disable it for some specific types - any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Post some code?

Comment: Looks like a (near) duplicate of [TypeNameHandling with attribute on a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43036371/3744182).  You would need to enhance the contract resolver in the accepted answer to apply a specified `TypeNameHandling` rather than just `TypeNameHandling.All`.  Does that answer your question, or do you need to see that enhancement?

Comment: @dbc yes, that answers it! (I had searched before asking, but didn't come across that one - I'll vote to close as a dupe too)

Comment: @Delphi.Boy code showing *what* precisely? I've described the settings I'm using now, and the question is specifically asking what code I might need to achieve a particular goal; I don't think there is any code I could add to the question that would add any further meaning.